Trigger action on pull request not working
I am trying to deploy a branch when a pull request is made to deploy the app to a Digital Ocean app platform container. I have based the workflow on the example code that Digital Ocean provided for this.
However creating a pull request is not triggering the action. I added a manual trigger but that is failing as it is expecting a pull request ID.
Can anyone help me diagnose the issue?
name: App Platform Preview

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ghactions]
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]

  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      pr_number:
        description: 'Pull Request Number'
        required: true
        type: number

permissions:
  contents: read
  pull-requests: write

jobs:
  deploy-admin:
    name: Deploy Admin
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Deploy the admin app
        id: deploy-admin
        uses: digitalocean/app_action/deploy@v2
        with:
          deploy_pr_preview: "true"
          token: ${{ secrets.DO_DEPLOY_EXPIRES_2025_12_17 }}
          app_spec_location: .do/admin/app.yaml

      - uses: actions/github-script@v7
        env:
          BUILD_LOGS: ${{ steps.deploy-admin.outputs.build_logs }}
          DEPLOY_LOGS: ${{ steps.deploy-admin.outputs.deploy_logs }}
        with:
          script: |
            const { BUILD_LOGS, DEPLOY_LOGS } = process.env;
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: ` The **admin app** was successfully deployed at ${{ fromJson(steps.deploy-admin.outputs.app).live_url }}.`
            });

      - uses: actions/github-script@v7
        if: failure()
        with:
          script: |
            const { BUILD_LOGS, DEPLOY_LOGS } = process.env;
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: `The **admin app** failed to be deployed. Logs can be found [here](https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}).
              ## Logs
              <details>
              <summary>Build logs</summary>
              \`\`\`
              ${BUILD_LOGS}
              \`\`\`
              </details>
              <details>
              <summary>Deploy logs</summary>
              \`\`\`
              ${DEPLOY_LOGS}
              \`\`\`
              </details>`
            });



Has that workflow file been merged into the default branch?

Are actions enabled for the repository? (and/or the organization)?

Is ghactions the base branch, or the head branch? pull_request.branches refers to the branch a PR is opened into, not from.

Yes ghactions is the base base branch. And actions are enabled and working. The issue seems to be specifying the branch. This works for example:
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing out GitHub Actions 
on: [pull_request, push]```

So if you add a branches filter to that workflow with [ghactions], it also stops working? I don't see how this wouldn't trigger if a PR were opened into ghactions.
